# Independent blocks on page

Tags: zend-framework2

First of all, sorry if my question is a little too general and too vague. I was searching for the right answer - but maybe i not know how to search.

I want to be able to place on page independent "blocks" - which will behave like ordinary action in the controller. So, as for example, will set them form it will be fully supported.

I know, of course, abotut place VieModel inside ViewModel - but it does not solve the whole problem.

I currently have a code like pasted below. But for example in  case of validation errors the results are displayed on a separate page

at the moment I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
class SettingsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function changeNameAction() {
        $changeNameView = new ViewModel();
        $form = new ChangeNameForm();
        $form->init();
        $form->setAttribute('action',$this->url()->fromRoute('settings/changeName'));
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('settings');
                }
            }
        }
        $changeNameView->setVariable('form',$form);
        $changeNameView->setTemplate('settings/changeName');
        return $changeNameView;
    }

    public function changeDomainAction() {
        $changeDomainView = new ViewModel();
        $form = new ChangeDomainForm();
        $form->setServiceLocator($this->getServiceLocator());
        $form->init();
        $form->setAttribute('action',$this->url()->fromRoute('settings/changeDomain'));

        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('settings');
                }
            }
        }
        $changeDomainView->setVariable('form',$form);
        $changeDomainView->setTemplate('settings/changeDomain');
        return $changeDomainView;
    }

    public function settingsAction() {

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->addChild($this->changeNameAction(), 'changeName');
        $view->addChild($this->changeLogoAction(), 'changeLogo');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

and of course I have 3 files view ( settings.phtml, changeLogo.phtml, changeName.phtml )

settings.phtml

```
<?= $changeName ?>
<?= $changeLogo ?>
```

changeName.phtml

```
<?= $this->form()->render($form); ?>
```

Comment: Why you just didn't use iframes?

Comment: It's not the nineties...:)